# Why am seeing boolean values in list when performing list comprehension?

Tags: python, file, search, list-comprehension

In iterating through a file and searching for occurrences of a few words in a file. I wrote list comprehension in trying to store matched words in a list for every read line.

```
search_strings = ["happy", "sad", "between"]
fio = open("text.txt", encoding="utf-8")
# reading file and trying to find occurences of search_string in text file
for line in fio:
    # first attempt: not what I wanted
    found_list_1 = [word in line for word in search_string]
    # second attempt: what I wanted
    found_list_2 = [word for word in search_string if word in line]
fio.close()
```

Result of printing out both constructed lists:

found_list_1 gives me boolean values when printing it out

```
[True, False, False]
```

found_list_2 returns the string found in every line read from the file.

```
["happy"]
```

I am trying to understand the behavior of list comprehension at found_list_1, why does it return boolean values instead of matched words?

Comment: The entries for `found_list_1` come from your expression `word in line` which returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[word in line for word in search_string] # For each word in search_string, does word exist in line?.


[word for word in search_string if word in line] #List all words in search_string that exist in line.
```

General Formula:

```
[<to be listed> for <variable> in <iterable> if <condition>]
```

Where `<to be listed>` usually: the `<variable>` itself, an expression that contains the `<variable>` (e.g `in`) or a function applied to the `<variable>` (e.g `sum`, `len`...).

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment, your found_list_1 should be:

```
found_list_1 = [word for word in search_string if word in line]
```

Comment: This is `found_list_2`. The question was why? ;)

Comment: I didn't even notice that!  The answer is in my comment for the original question.  The first list comprehension is storing `(word in line)` values, which are boolean.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

`found_list_1` gives you boolean information of occurencess of every `word in search_string` in `line`.

`found_list_2` filters `search_strings` and present only that `word` which occurs in `line`.

Lets examine:

```py
found_list_1 = [True, False, False]
search_strings = ["happy", "sad", "between"]
found_list_2 = ["happy"]
```

Comment: I see that now. Thanks mate :)